# why my document class is not applied?

Tags: line-spacing, document-classes

I'm so desperated, i'm writing the thesis and i can't configure the document-class.
I'm naive of latex, so if you need more file, comment and i will provide.
This is my document class, and the only attribute that dosen't works, it's line spacing. the onespacing is the only one that accept.

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
italian, % ngerman for German
doublespacing, %singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
```

Thank you for help
this is the [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

Comment: I have no problem using either `doublespacing`, `onehalfspacing ` or `singlespacing` with that template.

Comment: Can you give more information? What options *exactly* did you try?